# Oracle SQL - Invalid GROUP BY when using CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case-when

I am trying to add up repair hours for jobs that we do where we damage our own equipment (I know...it's crazy).

Essentially, I am hoping to be able to look at the TOTAL amount of Repair Hours for a part, and then also see how many hours are broken down via different TYPES of repair. My code is below, and I'm hoping to achieve this sort of goal:

[image]

My code is below:

```
SELECT 
            PART_NUM,
            PART_NAME,
            PART_SERIAL_NUM,
            SUM(REPAIR_HOURS) AS "TOTAL_REPAIR_HOURS",
            CASE WHEN REPAIR_TYPE = 'A' THEN SUM(REPAIR_HOURS) END AS "CONCRETE_HOURS",
            CASE WHEN REPAIR_TYPE = 'B' THEN SUM(REPAIR_HOURS) END AS "DEMOLITION_HOURS",
            CASE WHEN REPAIR_TYPE = 'C' THEN SUM(REPAIR_HOURS) END AS "AUTOMOTIVE_HOURS"

        FROM 
            PARTS
                LEFT JOIN REPAIRS
                     ON PART_NUM = REPAIRED_PART AND 
                        PART_SERIAL_NUM = REPAIRED_PART_SERIAL_NUM

        WHERE
            PART_NUM = '500ABX'

        GROUP BY 
            PART_NUM,
            PART_NAME,
            PART_SERIAL_NUM
```

(I am obviously only testing it on one part at a time :) )

I continually get the error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression (#979).

I have tried to take away the CASE WHEN statements, and it works fine. It is only when I am adding those in that I have a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Thanks @Vamsi Prabhala - I went to edit my own mistake and you fixed it before I did! :)

Comment: Repair_type is not in your grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the case expression *inside* the aggregate, not the other way round:

```
SELECT 
            PART_NUM,
            PART_NAME,
            PART_SERIAL_NUM,
            SUM(REPAIR_HOURS) AS "TOTAL_REPAIR_HOURS",
            SUM(CASE WHEN REPAIR_TYPE = 'A' THEN REPAIR_HOURS ELSE 0 END) AS "CONCRETE_HOURS",
            SUM(CASE WHEN REPAIR_TYPE = 'B' THEN REPAIR_HOURS ELSE 0 END) AS "DEMOLITION_HOURS",
            SUM(CASE WHEN REPAIR_TYPE = 'C' THEN REPAIR_HOURS ELSE 0 END) AS "AUTOMOTIVE_HOURS"

        FROM 
            PARTS
                LEFT JOIN REPAIRS
                     ON PART_NUM = REPAIRED_PART AND 
                        PART_SERIAL_NUM = REPAIRED_PART_SERIAL_NUM

        WHERE
            PART_NUM = '500ABX'

        GROUP BY 
            PART_NUM,
            PART_NAME,
            PART_SERIAL_NUM
```

Comment: this is brilliant. Thank you very much for explaining that to me. I knew I was close. I appreciate it!!

Comment: If I wanted to add a fourth option, other than "A" "B" or "C", if it was ANYTHING ELSE, how would that be done?

Comment: With another aggregated case expression, with whatever logic you need inside that.